# View helper is accessible in one controller, but not accessible from another

Tags: php, zend-framework, view, helper

I have a little strange situation.
I have view, from this view I execute my view helper "convertingText". This view helper (FR_View_Helper_ConvertingText.php) are locate in folder FR/View/Helper

No problem, helper works.

I created 404 page. This is not simple html page. This page are similar to main page - we output some items from database. I copied part of view in new view and I have problem convertingText view helper aren't loaded.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception' with message 'Plugin by name 'ConvertingText' in /var/www/framework/zend/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 336

Zend_Loader_PluginLoader_Exception: Plugin by name 'ConvertingText' was not found in the registry; used paths:
Zend_View_Helper_: Zend/View/Helper/:../application/views/helpers/:/var/www/current/application/modules/default/views/helpers/ in /var/www/framework/zend/library/Zend/Loader/PluginLoader.php on line 422
```

On Bootstrap.php we have lines with adding folder for loading helper

```
$view->addHelperPath("FR/View/Helper", "FR_View_Helper");
```

I debugged and output paths from method load class Zend_Loader_PluginLoader
And on main page I have different paths (for loading plugins) from paths on 404 page.

On main page I have these paths

```
/var/www/current/modules/movies/views/helpers/ConvertingText.php
FR/View/Helper/ConvertingText.php
```

On 404 page I have these paths

```
/var/www/current/application/modules/movies/views/helpers/ConvertingText.php
/var/www/current/application/modules/default/views/helpers/ConvertingText.php
../application/views/helpers/ConvertingText.php
Zend/View/Helper/ConvertingText.php
```

And one strange issue, if I add line

```
$view->convertingText('', '');
```

after line

```
$view->addHelperPath("FR/View/Helper", "FR_View_Helper");
```

in Bootstrap.php - view helper convertingText works on 404 page.

Why is so behaviour ?

```
protected function _initView()
{
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
    $view->addHelperPath("DR/View/Helper", "DR_View_Helper");
    $view->addHelperPath("FR/View/Helper", "FR_View_Helper");

    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
    $viewRenderer->setViewScriptPathSpec(":controller/:action.:suffix");
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);

    Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial(array('pagination.phtml','default'));

    Zend_Registry::set('view', $view);

    return $view;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, why view helper was unaccesible.

Paths to helpers are overrided. I found this code in one Plugin.

```
$this->view = Zend_Registry::get('view');
$this->view->setBasePath('../application/views/');
```

Executing method setBasePath overrided paths to my helpers.

Answer (score 1):

The different paths are probably dependent on which module you're in. You should use an absolute path for the view helper path, then you won't have this problem:

```
$view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH."/../FR/View/Helper", "FR_View_Helper");
```

(update as required.)

ZF reuses helper classes it's already loaded, so `$view->convertingText('', '');` fixes it because then the helper is loaded before the module changes.

**Edit**: Try this for your init view method:

```
protected function _initView()
{
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH."/../DR/View/Helper", "DR_View_Helper");
    $view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH."/../FR/View/Helper", "FR_View_Helper");

    $viewRenderer = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer($view);
    $viewRenderer->setViewScriptPathSpec(":controller/:action.:suffix");
    $stack = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStack();
    $stack->push($viewRenderer);

    Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial(array('pagination.phtml','default'));

    Zend_Registry::set('view', $view);

    return $view;
}
```

Comment: Only works if I add this code to my ErrorController.

(like so $this->view->addHelperPath(APPLICATION_PATH . "/../FR/View/Helper", "FR_View_Helper");

Replacing relative path to absolute in Bootstrap.php give the same result - main page works, 404 page - error.

Thanks for this

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment I posted only part of text.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the full method from your bootstrap class where you are adding the view path?

Comment: Added method _initView

Comment: The same situation with updated _initView method - main page works, 404 - convertingText not loaded. :(

Comment: Another helper "widget" from the same directory works fine on 404 page.

Comment: Well, the view object that's generating the error is not the one you're adding paths to. The problem is not in the code you've posted, there must be something else going on somewhere, I'm afraid it's hard for me to advise further.

Comment: Thanks, as a temporary solution I use adding path to helper in my error controller.

Comment: I found the problem, why my paths are overrided. I found this code in one Plugin.

    $this->view = Zend_Registry::get('view');
    $this->view->setBasePath('../application/views/');
        
Executing method setBasePath overrided paths to my helpers.

Comment: If you found the answer on yourself, please create a new answer an daccept it. Don't update your question or other answers with the solution. Follow the Q&A style of Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I think a trailing slash(/) and underscore(_) may be creating problem

```
protected function _initView()
{
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
    $view->addHelperPath($path . "/DR/View/Helper/", "DR_View_Helper_");//Add $path
    $view->addHelperPath($path . "/FR/View/Helper/", "FR_View_Helper_");//Add $path

    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('ViewRenderer');
    $viewRenderer->setViewScriptPathSpec(":controller/:action.:suffix");
    $viewRenderer->setView($view);
    Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addHelper($viewRenderer);

    Zend_View_Helper_PaginationControl::setDefaultViewPartial(array('pagination.phtml','default'));

    Zend_Registry::set('view', $view);

    return $view;
}
```

Comment: Did you replaced $path with your $path ?

Comment: @yAnTar is DR/View/Helper is inside libraries directory ?

Comment: Off course I replaced path, If i set incorrect path - I get error on both pages, if correct - main page works, 404 page not works.